# Verifying event handler exists in Moq vs Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, rhino-mocks

I want to be able to test whether a object has subscribed to an event. In Rhino Mocks the below code verifies this however I cannot find a way to do it in Moq.

```
public class Presenter
{
    IView view;
    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.Load += new EventHandler(view_Load);
    }
    void view_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not implemented.");
    }
}


[Test]
public void VerifyAttachesToViewEvents()
{
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
    IView viewMock = (IView)mocks.CreateMock(typeof(IView));
    using (mocks.Record())
    {
        viewMock.Load += null;
        LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
    }
    new Presenter(viewMock);
    mocks.VerifyAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a bug/feature missing in Moq http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=100

Answer (score 1):

I would raise the event and verify whether an exception has been thrown. Anyway you probably need to check if some logic in your SUT is executed not just that an event has been subscribed to:

```
[Test]
public void VerifyAttachesToViewEvents()
{
    // arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IView>();
    new Presenter(mock.Object);

    // act
    Action action = () => mock.Raise(view => view.Load += null, EventArgs.Empty);

    // assert
    action.ShouldThrow<Exception>()
        .WithMessage("Not implemented.");
}
```

I was not sure what unit testing framework you use, so leveraged [fluent assertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/) in the assert part. If you use NUnit the code may be:

```
[Test]
public void VerifyAttachesToViewEvents()
{
    // arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IView>();
    new Presenter(mock.Object);

    // act & assert
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => 
         mock.Raise(view => view.Load += null, EventArgs.Empty));
}
```

Comment: I'm using Moq framework, could you apply the code to that framework?

Comment: My example also uses Moq. But under "unit testing framework" I meant Nunit, MSTest etc. Moq is a "mock framework" :) Anyway I added example to NUnit.
However I would recommend you to take a look at fluent assertions -- they can be used together with NUnit/XUnit and Moq/Rhino/NSubstitute.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm using NUnit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer although doesn't really answer my initial question

Comment: I don't think so -- tests will fail if `this.view.Load += new EventHandler(view_Load);` is removed, but that's your question :)

Comment: Agreed the test would fail but if we dont have a exception being thrown then its tricky to determine what to verify/assert against

Comment: Well, anyway subscribing to event has sense only if there is some action that gets executed when event is fired. So you should test that action is executed, not that event got subscribed to. If you have any example when this is not true it would be interesting to investigate :)